# Touch test in VS2010 for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can someone tell me how to test the Touch function in VS2010 for Windows Phone 7 emulator? I wrote a simple phone 7 app to test touch function, when I move the mouse and click in side the phone screen, nothing happened.

-Henry

Answer (score 0):

The mouse does work for single finger gestures and taps, not sure why it wouldn't work for you except to assume that your code must not be working as you assume :-)

Just for reference, the other way of testing multi-touch is to have a multi-touch enabled monitor

Comment: Also, check out this site .. http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/. I think it includes drivers to use multiple mouse devices for the emulator.

Comment: Could you send me a simple working app with touch function? Do I need to install any additional drivers?